# Database scheme for storing sensor measurements

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I want to read different bio-sensor as well as tablet-sensor data and store them in a SQL database. The bio-sensor data are e.g. the skin conductance, the heart rate, the heart rate variability and so on. These are just numbers (with an unit). Regarding the tablet-sensor data I have touch input, acceleration, front cam, stylus input and so on. Basically these are also just numbers except for stylus and front cam.

Regarding the SQL database scheme I thought of creating a table with the columns *timestamp*, *user ID*, *tablet ID*, *sensor ID*, *unit* and *value*. The key would be (*timestamp*, *user ID*, *tablet ID*, *sensor ID*) because there can be measurements of different sensors at the same time. I'm recording all sensor values with the tablet (also the bio-sensor data), so there is always a tablet ID. That also means that the database is hold on the tablet. I'm using Android.

I don't know if these makes sense. Perhaps it would be good to have a separate table for every sensor. How would you make such a scheme or is there another proposal for a good scheme?

Second, how should I store stylus input and front cam (video) recordings? I thought of storing the video recording not in the database but external and then somehow linking from the database to this external file (e.g. through the file name).

There will be a lot of data to store. I will collect sensor data over 60 minutes and there are several values to write every second (e.g. for the bio-sensor data every 1/10 second there is a new value). So it could be a problem that the database gets too big or is too slow. By the way, I only want to write to the database. Reading the database I will do in a second (offline) step.

Comment: Does your table even need a key? Presumably you are just storing a big dump of data and that data is not going to be referenced from any other table...

Comment: @RB. Yes with only one table I don't need a key but as I have written I'm seeking for a better scheme with multiple tables.

Comment: @dan1111 Stylus and front cam input are not just numbers.

Comment: You might be better off using a NoSQL database, like MongoDB. You basically want to hold a load of completely disparate data, that share a small bit of metadata...

Comment: @RB. I have to say that I want to store all the things on a Android tablet and MongoDB is not available for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would lean toward a separate table for each sensor**.  The reasons:

- **It doesn't seem like you would typically want to analyse data for different sensors together**, since they represent different things.
- **You wouldn't have to store the unit or sensor ID.**  The storage savings may be significant, if you are dealing with a large volume of sensor readings--especially on a tablet environment with limited storage.
- **A shared table may have locking problems** if you are trying to insert records from multiple different sensors at a high rate.

**I would also create a single table to capture one period of interaction with the device.** Let's call it "session".

This would provide a key for the other tables, and also allow you to define what the video and stylus data files are associated with that session.

So you would have something like this:

```
session (
    session_id,
    user_id,
    tablet_id,
    video_file,
    stylus_data_file,
    session_start_time,
    session_end_time,
    ... any other session-level data ...
)
```

And then for each sensor have a table like:

```
heart_rate_readings (
    session_id,
    timestamp,
    value
)
```

*Note:* I don't know enough about the stylus data to give an informed opinion.  The above assumes it will be stored in a separate file.  But if it is just a stream of coordinates you are receiving, you might consider also storing it in a separate table in the database.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Should I use transactions (and if so, when to commit) or should I put every sensor reading into one transaction? Second, should I use a thread for each sensor which handles the database (insert of new row)?

Comment: Different tables for each sensor is terrible database design. It just does not scale and even after just a couple of sensors has administrative overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:

I'd assume that the data for each sensor always uses the same unit. That is, if sensor #7 gives a value in ohms today, it's not going to give a value in millimeters tomorrow. More plausibly, I suppose there could be some setting to let you switch between inches and centimeters, etc. But if the unit is always the same, then don't store the unit in the same table with the values. Have a separate "sensor" table that gives the unit for that sensor, probably other information about the sensor, like a name.

Whether to have one table per sensor or a separate table for each sensor: Big advantage of one table is that if you add a new sensor, you don't have to change the schema, it's just data: Add a record to the sensor table and you're done. If there's lots of data this table could get big. But each record is pretty small: I presume sensor ID and tablet ID can be int's. User ID might be an int or a guid.

I've never tried to store a video in a database. I've stored images and those are huge compared to other data. A video is normally at least megabytes. My gut feel would be to store them as individual files and just store a filename. I'll happily yield to anyone who's actually tried putting videos in a DB and can say how it turned out.

Comment: Should I use transactions (and if so, when to commit) or should I put every sensor reading into one transaction? Second, should I use a thread for each sensor which handles the database (insert of new row)?

Comment: I'd guess that sensor readings are valid independently. I mean, if you get the heart rate but for some reason the system fails getting the blood pressure, the heart rate is probably still a good and useful measurement. Assuming that's true, they shouldn't be transactions.  If there are readings that are only meaningful when taken together, there might be a case for transactions. The normal reason to use transactions is to prevent an inconsistent state, like trying to transfer money between two accounts, so you subtract from one, but then fail trying to add to the other, and so now the money...

Comment: ... has just disappeared.

Comment: RE use threads: I don't see an inherent reason why threading is necessary or helpful. It might be good for performance reasons. How do you get the sensor readings? Are they interrupts? Do you have to poll? This gets into all sorts of questions about the language and OS you're using, which is a totally separate issue from the DB.

Comment: I'm using SQLLite on Android. What I have read is that there can only be one database connection at the same time, i.e. all threads must share the same connection. I'm getting the sensor readings by interrupts (events), I don't have to poll. Of course having only one db connection is a bottleneck.